# Grab docstrings from scripts in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a code repository which is a mix of modules and analytical scripts.  I am trying to document it with Sphinx.

```
-MyProject
    -MyModule
    -Scripts_using_MyModule
        -Specific_Analytical_Question_1.py
        -Specific_Analytical_Question_2.py
```

Using `.. automodule::` I can grab the docstrings from the modules in the MyModule folder.  But I would also like to take the docstrings that I have written in the scripts.  What I mean by scripts are small pieces of code for a very specific purpose, they are not written as functions so that you can see all the variables when they run in Spyder.

Is there a way to give Sphinx the folder name and have it list all the files with their docstrings?

Comment: Pyramid may have a similar structure to what you want. It has a [directory of modules and a subdirectory of scripts](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/pyramid). Then we use Sphinx plugins to render each the API docstrings with [`autodoc`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L53) and the script docstrings with [`autoprogram`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L58). https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/index.html https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/pscripts/prequest.html

Comment: There is a sphinx extension that will generate pages from Python programs including their docstrings and graphical output via matplotlib. https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/ I use it to document a small computing library and it is very convenient. It is not exactly what you ask, but you might consider trying it :-) The project lists some nice examples on its "getting started" page.

Comment: Did you try to list all your script folders in the conf.py? You should add each folder with "sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('path relative to your Sphinx working directory'))".